# Equalizing fractions

Tags: code-golf, math, rational-numbers

When I was in grade 3, we were taught how to solve a very simple math problem. It was equaling the denominators of two or more fractions.

Let's take two proper fractions:-

$$
\frac{1}{2},\frac{2}{3}
$$

First we will take the Least Common Multiple of the denominators of the two fractions, the LCM of \$2,3\$ are \$6\$. Then we divide the LCM (\$6\$) by the denominators of both fractions (\$6\$) and we get \$3,2\$ and serially multiply them with the numerators of the both fractions and get

$$
\frac{3}{6},\frac{4}{6}
$$

And that's the result.

## Challenge

Take two or more fractions, and equalize their denominators.

## I/O format

You can take an array/list of `(numerator,denominator)` pairs. Pre-defining them in TIO header is allowed. You can take in other better ways too.

```
Input: ((1,2),(2,3)) or
        1,2 2,3
        1/2 2/3
Output: (3,6),(4,6) or 
        3,6 4,6 
        3/6 4/6
Input:  ((1, 8), (5, 12))
       1,8 5,12
       1/8 5/12
Output: ((3, 24), (10, 24))
         3,24 10,24
         3/24 10/24
Input: ((1, 2),(2, 3),(4, 6))
Output: 3/6 4/6 4/6
```

## Rules

- [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden. (except use of TIO headers to pre-define input)
- Trailing whitespace in output is allowed.
- If possible, please link to an online interpreter (e.g. [TIO](https://tio.run)) to run your program on.
- Please explain your answer. This is not necessary, but it makes it easier for others to understand.
- Languages newer than the question are allowed. This means you could create your own language where it would be trivial to do this, but don't expect any upvotes.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code in bytes wins!

Comment: If we are actually to use the LCM and not simply the product of the denominators, could you provide a test case such as `((1, 8), (5, 12)) -> ((3, 24), (10, 24))`? Also will the input fractions be irreducible.

Comment: @ophact yes input fractions can be proper or improper. And you have to take the LCM of denominators not products. My question was in [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges/21946#21946) for a few days, why didn't people give feedback there, and once question is posted there are (or will be) numerous feedbacks, making the fate of this question being closed again.

Comment: Can we take two lists `[numerators]` and `[denominators]` as input?

Comment: @Delfad0r yes you can

Comment: Just noticed that... may I assume the input fractions are already simplified? For example, "2/4" will not appear in the input.

Comment: Sorry to bother again, but if non-simplified fractions can appear in the input (as it looks like from the last testcase), you may consider adding a testcase like `2/4, 3/6`, where computing the LCM of the denominators is not enough.

Comment: Can we output all numerator and one denominator?

Comment: @I4m2 no you can't

Comment: @Wasif You posted in the sandbox yesterday. Then you post today complaining that it might be treated as if you didn't post to the sandbox at all! T_T Wait a few days for feedback from the sandbox posting and then you won't be in such dilemma.

Comment: @Noodle9 i posted 2 days ago, i think the cause may be a lot of other sandbox questions made it go to another page, and also it was posted at a time when users are less online

Comment: @Wasif Sandbox says yesterday. Regardless, wait for feedback. That's the whole point of posting there.

Comment: Also, people are always going to ask for clarifications on main, it's much more active than the Sandbox. So long as you address those clarifications within a reasonable amount of time, no-one's going to close the question

Comment: Are all numbers in the input positive integers?

Comment: @ChartZBelatedly yes

Comment: I'm voting to close as unclear because it's not apparent to me from the challenge how non-reduced fractions are handled.

Comment: @xnor non-reduced fractions, no need to reduce them, please save me this time, please don't close, I am requesting badly

Comment: @Wasif As in, we just take the denominators and numerators as given without simplifying them? You should edit your clarification into the question and add some relevant test cases.

Comment: Suggested testcase: `((1, 2),(2, 3),(8, 12))`

Comment: You have many choices to clarity the question: 1. Change the rule to: Inputs will never contain non-reduced fractions (or input with non-reduced factions may lead to undefined behaviors), change last testcase to avoid it; 2. Clarity that input may contain non-reduced fractions, and answers should always use LCM of denominator, add a testcase `(2/4, 3/6) -> (6/12, 6/12)`; 3. Clarity that input may contain no-reduced factions, and answers should not use LCM of denominator, but the smallest possible value, add a testcase `(2/4, 3/6) -> (1/2, 1/2)`;

Comment: Also, you need to add your comment to "Are all numbers in the input positive integers" into the question. Not only leave it in comment.

Answer (score 7):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 63 bytes

```javascript
f=(a,t=1)=>a.some(v=>t%v[1])?f(a,1+t):a.map(([p,q])=>[p*t/q,t])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZcrBCgIhEADQe/8RODUZGkEsuH2IzGHYNIrd1c3B3zc7d37vzZXL9HllOa3pEVqLTjGKM@BG1iUtQVU3yr56Q3CP3cxRYGC9cFbKZ9yoT58Pct5QCNqU1pLmoOf0VFF5b9ASeosXIoDdv966XtHYH7cv)

---

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 63 bytes

```javascript
f=(a,t,b=a.map(([p,q])=>[m=p*t/q,o&=m%1||t],o=t))=>o?b:f(a,-~t)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZctBCsIwEEDRvfdQEplWEhGkMPYgQxZpbURpOqkduipePca18HeP//KrX/r3M0k18X3IAUvKg0CHvo4@KUUJZqfxRhHTUU4z8AHj3mybOGAUXYjbrgnlqj6ic8/TwuNQj/xQQREZsA7Iwtk5rXf/ei16AWN/nL8)

`m=p*t/q` cannot be changed to `p*=t/q` due to floating point errors. For example, `11*15/11` is `15`, but `11*(15/11)` is `14.999999999999998`. :(

- The first answer here will output `[[6, 12], [6, 12]]`  for input `[[2, 4], [3, 6]]`.
- The second one will output `[[1, 2], [1, 2]]` for input `[[2, 4], [3, 6]]`.

---

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 62 bytes

- [@Arnauld](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58563/arnauld) had modified the code to make it work in 62 bytes. This one would support positive fractions.

```javascript
f=(a,t,o=-~t,b=a.map(([p,q])=>[p*t/q,t+=p*t%q]))=>t<o?b:f(a,o)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY1BDoIwEEXXeIpuTIoOYAsoNVYP0nRREYwGaZHGpVfHCZiYqJnNm595f67mYfryfnE@au2pGoZaUgMerIyeHo7SxDfjKFUOOh3KvXILn3TglxJhjhFmfmcPx22Nmg2H0ra9baq4sWdaU6UYcA2KQ6rxNgiShCicFMiaaEDKRiJ69isWKObA@LfJs0llq4n/yFkOAu1CABu/MzaWvDvyHAhjU4nYiM/CJyR6eAE)

Answer (score 5):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 20 bytes

```
LCM@@(q=Last/@#)/q#&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n27738fZ18FBo9DWJ7G4RN9BWVO/UFntf0BRZl6JgkN6dHW1oY6CUa2OQrWRjoJxbW0sF6qUBUjKVEfB0AhTDqENSJvoKJgBlfz/DwA)

Fractions are in the form `{numerator, denominator}`
We simply multiply the fractions by the LCM of denominators divided by the denominators

Answer (score 5):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), <s>73</s> 64 bytes

-9 bytes thanks to chunes!

```
[ dup 1 [ lcm ] reduce [ swap n/v v* dup length ] keep <array> ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY9PC8IwDMXvfop3Fpxu/kFUvIoXL@JJPJQa3djW1aabDOlnn7VDkRzykvzySG5C2sp0p@P@sFtBMFeSkZNRVKAUNo1utZI2qxSD6VGTksT9oKHPJkMYI1qGNmRtq02mLNaDFz4RI4HzOcHUZxd6U8yCWvj49mIsg5ojTv7ApCfjSa/cz3P2c@09XHfGtdZ@dkYhS1xg6FpL8iU/hYYaN2iGASlI3W3qiZxIYxOO3@LShc9HpYej7g0)

Takes the input as two separate lists for numerators and denominators

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 73 bytes

```
[ unzip dup 1 [ lcm ] reduce swap over [ n/v v* ] dip '[ _ 2array ] map ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY7NCsIwEAbvfYrvJnhQGn8QfQDx4kU8FZGQbrHYJnGTVGrps9dUPPSyCzOzsIVU3vBwvZzOxz2exJoqSOeMcqilfyyKoJUvjXZw9AqkFf1FQ@Olg2SWrUPBLSyT963lUnuUBoekSzp0SCHQxy2wirv/s92PbZCKCZyGHdbYjg5Jn2DIEPSntMiDjWGGStW4gSkPiuDe0sI0xFHoZYNmHl0e61mGO8Tvx0jqWN2GcS6GLw)

Takes the input as a list of (numerator,denominator) pairs.

I thought it would be shorter using fractions but I didn't manage to make it nice. Except this the Factor version TIO has normalizes the fractions.

Comment: We came up with [similar answers](https://tio.run/##TY9PC8IwDMXvfop3Fpxu/kFUvIoXL@JJPJQa3djW1aabDOlnn7VDkRzykvzySG5C2sp0p@P@sFtBMFeSkZNRVKAUNo1utZI2qxSD6VGTksT9oKHPJkMYI1qGNmRtq02mLNaDFz4RI4HzOcHUZxd6U8yCWvj49mIsg5ojTv7ApCfjSa/cz3P2c@09XHfGtdZ@dkYhS1xg6FpL8iU/hYYaN2iGASlI3W3qiZxIYxOO3@LShc9HpYej7g0 "Factor – Try It Online"), but I took the input as two separate lists for numerators and denominators.

Comment: @chunes Thanks for sharing! Feel free to post it as a separate submission.

Comment: @chunes I updated the post using your solution - tahnks again!

Answer (score 4):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <sup>14</sup> 10 bytes

```
,.**./@]%]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/dfS0tPT0HWJVY/9rcnGlJmfkKxgqGCmkAbExhKuuDhM2BQpbKBgaoYsbKZhANCiY/QcA)

<sup>-4 after realizing taking a list of numerators and a list of denominators was allowed</sup>

Works like `<list of numerators> f <list of denominators>`.

- `*./@]` LCM of denominators (right hand arg)...
- `%]` Divided elementwise by the denominators...
- `,.*` Times the zip of the numerators and denominators.

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 45 bytes

```hs
n#d=($d).zipWith(div.(*foldr1 lcm d))<$>[n,d]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PczNCgIhFEDhfU8xMLPwxkXQfmiRvUHrFiIhOjGSmqgT1MtbUbT8OHAmXa6j963F3goyWKBPl06uTsS6OyXLy83bzDpvQmcB9sNBRrSq1bFUo8tYhCSSIVcoOa4U4Eebt3bI@I8c19@MWwVqEbSLIuh0PJOUXax0jmbO@UF6gP@2vQA)

Takes two lists (`n=numerators` and `d=denominators`) as input, returns two lists with the same format as output. Assumes fractions in the input are reduced.

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <sup><s>72</s> <s>69</s></sup> 66 bytes

```hs
f x|l<-foldr(\(n,d)->lcm.div d$gcd n d)1x=[(div(n*l)d,l)|(n,d)<-x]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PcxNDoIwEAXgvafowsWMGUiKP3EB3sATYGMaBpQwVEIbw4K7VzTq8nvv5d2t72qRGBs1zZInzUN4hAs4YkxOUvUpt0/F61vFyilGPRUlLBG4jSCT4PyZ5slkYqh9qKyvfVGWoClDgoy2aOit46I96ezLX0mwowMas@pt64reDucrDGPrQtrg/y@@AA)

Takes a list of pairs as input, returns a list of pairs as output. Works for unreduced fractions as well.

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 79 bytes

```hs
f x|let(z,l)=foldr(\(n,d)(y,a)->((div(n*l)d,l):y,lcm(d`div`gcd n d)a))([],1)x=z
```

Takes a list of pairs as input, returns a list of pairs as output. Works for unreduced fractions as well.

Quite a bit longer than the other answer, but I decided to post it anyway since there is some Haskell magic going on! The LCM of the (reduced) denominators `l` appears both on the left hand side and the right hand side of the `let` expression. This is only possible because of Haskell's lazyness.

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 57 bytes

```ruby
->l{k=l.reduce(1){|s,x|s.lcm x[1]};l.map{|a,b|[a*k/b,k]}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FctBCoAgEEDRq7SKisnQCIKoiwyz0NKNBlEEhXp2s9XjL/55qzeZObWL83Z27NTbveqK1z5c8ISLuXUvHuQUJ8d2efggQQWUje0UWIoxHQUichgJcAAuKJtTZAT0RPRfVWnq9AE)

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>9</s> 8 bytes

```
aæl/Ṅ:Ʋ×
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/x8LIc/Yc7W6yObTo8/f///9FGOsY6ZrH/ow11jHRMYgE)

Full program. Takes a list of denominators \$[d_1, d_2, ...]\$ on the left and a list of numerators \$[n_1, n_2, ...]\$ on the right. Outputs a list of denominators, then a list of numerators

Would be [7 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///wshz9hztbrI51HZ7@////aCMdYx2z2P/RhjpGOiaxAA) if we could just output the dominator once.

### How it works

```
aæl/Ṅ:Ʋ× - Main link. Takes denominators D on the left and numerators N on the right
      Ʋ  - Group the previous 4 links into a monad on D:
 æl/     -   Reduce by LCM
a        -   AND; Replace each element in D with the LCM
    Ṅ    -   Print the list of LCM
     :   -   Divide each by the corresponding element of D
       × - Multiply this list with N elementwise
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 33 bytes

```
K1JEFkJ=K/*kKikK;FkE[/*kKhJK)=JtJ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/39vQy9Ut28vWW18r2zsz29vaLds1GsTO8PLWtPUq8fr/P9pIR8FYxyyWK9pQx0jHJBYA)

Takes two lines of input: first line should contain the list of denominators, and the second line should contain the list of corresponding numerators.

## Explanation

```
K1       # Initialize K to 1
JE       # Initialize J to evaluated input (in this case, list of denominators)
FkJ      # For loop over elements of J, with iterator as k
=K       # Set K to
*kK      # Product of k and K
ikK      # GCD of k and K
/        # Divide them to get the LCM
FkE      # Another for loop over the next evaluated input (the numerators)
hJ       # First element of J
/*kKhJ   # Convert the numerator accordingly
K        # Denominator
[...)    # Put that inside a list and print it
tJ       # Tail J (first element removed)
=J       # Assign J to it
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 99 bytes

```python
import numpy
f=lambda a,i=0,k=1:i<len(a)and f(a,i+1,numpy.lcm(k,a[i][1]))or[(p*k//q,k)for p,q in a]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TctLDsIgFIXheVdxh6A3VmhMTCMrIQyuViKhPEpw0NUjOnJ6vvPnvb5SnFpzIadSIb5D3gerVgr3hYDQqTN6JWZ3W5@REae4gGV9Pwr8nU/rIzCPpJ3RwnCeimb54MdxQ89tKpBxAxeBTMvFxcos01rg1aC@oJCmJ8M/gOwiEaavtA8)

Takes a list of lists and computes the LCM of denominators. This result is stored in `k` and at the end the fractions are converted to the same denominator (`k`).

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 82 bytes

```
\d+
*
+`(_+)/((_+)(\3)*) (_+)/(?!\2\b)(\3)+\b
$#6*$1/$#6*$2 $#4*$5$5/$#6*$2
_+
$.&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYlLDsIwDET3PoVRrSqJJYydpuqOi1jqR3TBhgXi/gHSbmbmvXnvn@dr1Vr9wZCAlzBzlPDP4DmmiIe4X9x8a459A@rGRCqtDKkbEhUqJ8PMQNe@VhVDkwwqExZRg1PgICNksdtvaGnXFw) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
\d+
*
```

Convert to unary.

```
+`
```

Repeat until all denominators are equal.

```
(_+)
```

Match a numerator...

```
/((_+)(\3)*)
```

... and the largest factor of a denominator...

```
 (_+)
```

... and another numerator...

```
/(?!\2\b)(\3)+\b
```

... and a denominator that is not equal to the first denominator but with the shared (greatest) common divisor.

```
$#6*$1/$#6*$2 $#4*$5$5/$#6*$2
```

Multiply the first fraction by the multiplicity `$#6` of the GCD in the second fraction, and also update the second fraction.

```
_+
$.&
```

Convert to decimal.

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 30 bytes

```
≔Ｅθ⊟ιη≔¹ζＷ⌈﹪ζη≦⊕ζＩＥθ⟦÷×ζ⊟ι§ηκζ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY4/D8IgFMR3PwXjI8HBalycGl06NOngRhhIIULkTy20Nv3yCLE6vVze/e6uV3zsPTcp1SHoh4OWD/AiqPMDaIwJUviy214Hgtas3kobibJx0Xay0HoxGQ9rsWKMMr/ZG9eP0koXpfiC3ahdhCsP8ddCGxdvetZCwl1bGUrKv7mOjRNyAUXQs@iV5fxLSpTSvKRiGa8IOpZ7IujMGEv72XwA) Link is to verbose version of code. I/O is standard Charcoal array format. Explanation: Uses brute force.

```
≔Ｅθ⊟ιη
```

Get the denominators.

```
≔¹ζ
```

Assume the LCM is 1.

```
Ｗ⌈﹪ζη≦⊕ζ
```

Keep incrementing the LCM until all the denominators divide it.

```
ＩＥθ⟦÷×ζ⊟ι§ηκζ
```

Scale the fractions to the new denominator.

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>69</s> 66 bytes

*Edit: -3 bytes thanks to Giuseppe*

```r
function(m)m/m[,2]*which(!rowSums(outer(1:prod(m),m[,2],"%%")))[1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bcxBCsIwEIXhfU8RK4UZGahJYxHBU7gsXUi0NNA0JU2onj5GF@qiDG9WP5@LszbToLvnOXZhVF7bEQya0jQk2t3Sa9XDxtnlEswMNvi7A36anL2lij4R5UWRI2LD2y8G5uqdfoACTiJdhSQQ2ZZVZc1kWrZWHuhIXPxSIRnfp5@ts/INU41J/6fT4gs)

Input & output as 2-column matrices, with each row representing a pair of numerator & denominator.

Comment: [66 bytes](https://tio.run/##bcxBCsIwEIXhfU8RK4UZGahJYxHBU7gsXUi0NNA0JU2onj5GF@qiDG9WP5@LszbToLvnOXZhVF7bEQya0jQk2t3Sa9XDxtnlEswMNvi7A36anL2lij4R5UWRI2LD2y8G5uqdfoACTiJdhSQQ2ZZVZc1kWrZWHuhIXPxSIRnfp5@ts/INU41J/6fT4gs)

Comment: @Giuseppe - Thanks.  Nice exploitation of ```which``` bringing the elements into-order to avoid the need for ```min```.  I like it.

Answer (score 0):

## Excel, 130 bytes

```
=LET(n,COUNT(A:A),b,OFFSET(B1,,,n),q,SEQUENCE(PRODUCT(b)),MIN(IF(MMULT(1*(MOD(q,TRANSPOSE(b))=0),b^0)=n,q,""))/b*OFFSET(A1,,,n,2))
```

Uses columns A&B for input

```
=LET(
n,COUNT(A:A)                                                            ' Number of fractions
b,OFFSET(B1,,,n)                                                        ' List of denominators
q,SEQUENCE(PRODUCT(b))                                                  ' 1..product of all denominators
MIN(IF(MMULT(1*(MOD(q,TRANSPOSE(b))=0),b^0)=n,q,""))/b*OFFSET(A1,,,n,2) ' final calculation
             1*(MOD(q,TRANSPOSE(b))=0)                                  ' matrix of q by b where 1 indicates q mod b = 0
    IF(MMULT(                         ,b^0)=n,q,"")                     ' if q is divisible by all n numbers then q else "" (list of all common multiples)
MIN(                                               )                    ' least common multiple
                                                    /b*OFFSET(A1,,,n,2) ' multiply each row by the number need to change denominator to LCM
```

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 9 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
.¿©¹÷*®δ‚
```

Input as two separated lists, first the list of denominator, second the list of numerator.
Output as a list of pairs of [numerator, denominator].

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##ASoA1f9vc2FiaWX//y7Cv8KpwrnDtyrCrs604oCa//9bMiwzLDZdClsxLDIsNF0) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfWVCsUvof71D@w@tjDi8XevQunNbHjXM@q/zPzo62kjHOFYn2lDHKDZWRyE62kLH0AjMN4XwgdI6ZhAFOiaxsbEA).

**Explanation:**

```python
.¿         # Get the Least Common Multiple (LCM) of the first (implicit) input-list of 
           # denominators
  ©        # Store this value in variable `®` (without popping)
   ¹÷      # Integer-divide it by each value of the first input-list
     *     # Multiply each value at the same positions to the second (implicit)
           # input-list of numerators
       δ   # For each value:
      ® ‚  #  Pair it with the stored LCM of variable `®`
           # (after which the resulting list of pairs is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Julia](http://julialang.org/), 22 bytes

```
n$d=(l=lcm(d))n./d.=>l
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/P08lxVYjxzYnOVcjRVMzT08/Rc/WLue/Q3FGfrlCtKGOUaxKtJGOcSwXVMRYxwQoYqZjBhcx1DEFiljoGBohKTI0AOkz0TEyQVJnBNYLNA1Ft5GOBVQUaMJ/AA)

- expects `[numerators] $ [denominators]`
- outputs an array of pairs : `[num1 => den1, num2 => den2,...]`
- could be [20 bytes](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/P08lxVYjxzYnOVcjRVMzT08/RSfnv0NxRn65QrShjlGsSrSRjnEsF1TEWMcEKGKmYwYXMdQxBYpY6BgaISkyNADpM9ExMkFSZwTWCzQNRbeRjgVUFGjCfwA) with the denominator only once in the ouput